# bitbuckes and privacy

Tags: github, bitbucket

I've created an account on BitBucket.org and was going to upload my code on it. Now, wondering if it will allow public have access to the code like GitHub as it does if you go with free account.

Does anybody have experience with it?

Comment: Oh come on. Basic questions aren't necessarily bad, but the site (and the repository creation process) is very explicit about it, so I must assume you didn't do research.

Comment: Not a question for this site, but yes, repos can be private. I have several private projects up on the site without having paid a dollar.

Comment: I looked at its FAQ but didn't find it but OK if you say so then i'm good with the negative scores.  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs are pretty clear](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Making+a+Repository+Private+or+Public)

Someone didn't make any attempt at all.

Comment: now some people who enjoy scoring others can stop it. it seems fun